# Why the event object is undefined in my case

Tags: javascript, events

When click on a button, I want to get the event object `e` in the modern browsers like `Firefox`, `Chrome`,`etc`.
the problem is when click on the button give me an `undefined` event object, note that when use `window.event` in `internet explorer` browser gets the event object.

```
// the Object
var countdown = {
    hours: 0,
    minutes: 0,
    seconds: 0,
    element_h: null,
    element_m: null,
    element_s: null,
    init: function (hElemId, mElemId, sElemId) {
        this.element_h = document.getElementById(hElemId);
        this.element_m = document.getElementById(mElemId);
        this.element_s = document.getElementById(sElemId);
    },
    play: function (e){
        alert(e.target);
    }
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick="countdown.play();">Play</button>
```

Comment: can you show the full source?
the part of your source is looks like correct

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to explicitly pass the `event` object to the onclick handler, like this

```
<button onclick="countdown.play(event);">Play</button>
```

Quoting [MDN's Event Registration Doc page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#HTML_attribute),

> The JavaScript code in the attribute is passed the Event object via the event parameter.

When you register an event handler inline, it can be given the `Event` object with the `event` parameter. This will not be done automatically though. That is why we have to explicitly pass the `event` object. Since you didn't pass it, `e` is `undefined` by default.

Comment: the keyword `event` is must be added as is or I can change the word to anything?

Comment: @LionKing `event` refers to the `window.event` object. So, it has to be exactly the same.

Comment: There is any way to pass the `event` parameter inside the object not outside, because when use the object the user doesn't know if must add `event` parameter or not. I want the easy way to the user which uses this object.

Comment: @LionKing The best way to include event listeners is to use `addEventListener`. You don't have to write the `onclick` attribute at all and `addEventListener` is the preferred way going forward. See the advantages of using it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Why_use_addEventListener.3F). So, to answer your question, no, its not possible in the way you register event handlers.

Answer (score 3):

The event object is passed to the event handler as the first parameter by the name `event` (or in the case of IE a global variable). You would pick up the parameter/variable and pass it on to the method.

Note that IE8 and older doesn't support the `target` property, so you need to use the `srcElement` property for those:

```js
var countdown = {
    hours: 0,
    minutes: 0,
    seconds: 0,
    element_h: null,
    element_m: null,
    element_s: null,
    init: function (hElemId, mElemId, sElemId) {
        this.element_h = document.getElementById(hElemId);
        this.element_m = document.getElementById(mElemId);
        this.element_s = document.getElementById(sElemId);
    },
    play: function (e){
        alert(e.target || e.srcElement);
    }
};
```

```html
<button onclick="countdown.play(event);">Play</button>
```

Comment: This is good, but don't most browsers support using `event` within inline event attributes? (For backwards compatibility with older IE.) Or is the `arguments[0]` test necessary with the latest browsers?

Comment: @nnnnnn is correct. There's no need for `arguments[0] ||` as long as the parameter is spelled out in full as `event`.

Comment: @nnnnnn: After some testing, I verified that they do. Also for backwards compatibility with IE8 and older we have to use the `srcElement` as they don't support the `target` property.

Answer (score 2):

> *"Why the event object is undefined in my case"*

Here's why. When you bind an inline handler, what happens is that an anonymous function is created and put on the element's `onclick` property.

Depending on the browser, that handler will look either like these:

```
// IE 8 and lower
elem.onclick = function() {
    countdown.play(); // <-- Invoking your method, but not passing anything
}


// Other browsers
elem.onclick = function(event) {
    countdown.play(); // <-- Invoking your method, but not passing anything
}
```

So both versions have a pretty obvious issue. You're calling your function without passing anything to it.

---

This is why you need to define an `event` parameter in your call.

```
<button onclick="countdown.play(event);">Play</button>
```

Now it'll look like these:

```
// IE 8 and lower
elem.onclick = function() {
    countdown.play(event); // <-- there's no parameter, but there is `window.event`
}


// Other browsers
elem.onclick = function(event) {
    countdown.play(event); // <-- it's just passing the parameter
}
```

Now it looks right. In IE8 and lower, there's no `event` parameter in the function, but it'll get the global `event` object.

In the second version, it's just passing along the parameter that was defined by the browser.

---

This also shows why you can't use `e` or some other name.

```
<button onclick="countdown.play(e);">Play</button>
```

Because you'll be passing a variable that's not defined anywhere.

```
// IE 8 and lower
elem.onclick = function() {
    countdown.play(e); // <-- there's no `e` defined in here
}


// Other browsers
elem.onclick = function(event) {
    countdown.play(e); // <-- there's no `e` defined in here
}
```