# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stopPropagation')

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, onclicklistener, addeventlistener

`stopPropagation()` is not working in my code. What is the issue?

When you will click on button then a dropdown will toggle and I want to hide this toggle when user click on anywhere on page.

```js
var iconListBoxBody;

function btnCrypto(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  iconListBoxBody = document.getElementById("iconListBoxBody");
  iconListBoxBody.classList.toggle("active");
}

document.body.addEventListener("click", function() {
  iconListBoxBody.classList.remove("active");
});
```

```css
.iconListBoxBody {
  display: none;
}

.iconListBoxBody.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="iconListBox">
  <div class="iconListBoxHeader">
    <img src="assets/images/coin1.png" alt="">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="BTC" />
    <button class="btn-crypto btn btn-primary" onclick="btnCrypto()"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>click</button>
  </div>
  <div class="iconListBoxBody" id="iconListBoxBody">
    <ul class="iconListBoxBodyList">
      <li>
        <img src="assets/images/coin1.png" alt="">
        <span class="coinText">BTC</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="assets/images/coin2.png" alt="">
        <span class="coinText">ETH</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the event object is undefined in my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465788/why-the-event-object-is-undefined-in-my-case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot to pass `event` param, I changed `onclick="btnCrypto()"` to `onclick="btnCrypto(event)"`:

```js
var iconListBoxBody;

function btnCrypto(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  iconListBoxBody = document.getElementById("iconListBoxBody");
  iconListBoxBody.classList.toggle("active");
}

document.body.addEventListener("click", function() {
  iconListBoxBody.classList.remove("active");
});
```

```css
.iconListBoxBody {
  display: none;
}

.iconListBoxBody.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="iconListBox">
  <div class="iconListBoxHeader">
    <img src="assets/images/coin1.png" alt="">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="BTC" />
    <button class="btn-crypto btn btn-primary" onclick="btnCrypto(event)"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>click</button>
  </div>
  <div class="iconListBoxBody" id="iconListBoxBody">
    <ul class="iconListBoxBodyList">
      <li>
        <img src="assets/images/coin1.png" alt="">
        <span class="coinText">BTC</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="assets/images/coin2.png" alt="">
        <span class="coinText">ETH</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Added JavaScript event listeners.

```js
var iconListBoxBody;

function btnCrypto(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  iconListBoxBody = document.getElementById("iconListBoxBody");
  iconListBoxBody.classList.toggle("active");
}

document.body.addEventListener("click", function() {
  iconListBoxBody.classList.remove("active");
});

document.querySelectorAll(".btn-crypto").forEach(el => (el.onclick = btnCrypto))
```

```css
.iconListBoxBody {
  display: none;
}

.iconListBoxBody.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="iconListBox">
  <div class="iconListBoxHeader">
    <img src="assets/images/coin1.png" alt="">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="BTC" />
    <button class="btn-crypto btn btn-primary">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>click</button>
  </div>
  <div class="iconListBoxBody" id="iconListBoxBody">
    <ul class="iconListBoxBodyList">
      <li>
        <img src="assets/images/coin1.png" alt="">
        <span class="coinText">BTC</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="assets/images/coin2.png" alt="">
        <span class="coinText">ETH</span>
      </li>


    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's only one `btn-crypto` so `querySelectorAll` seems superfluous. And if the OP is using `addEventListener` you should use it too instead of `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `addEventListener` already, remove the inline JS calling the `btnCrypt` function, and use `addEventListener` to add it to the cached button element.

```js
// Cache your elements
const iconListBoxBody = document.querySelector('.iconListBoxBody');
const button = document.querySelector('.btn-crypto');

function btnCrypto(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  iconListBoxBody.classList.add('active');
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', function() {
  iconListBoxBody.classList.remove('active');
});

button.addEventListener('click', btnCrypto);
```

```css
.iconListBoxBody { display: none; }
.active { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="iconListBox">
  <div class="iconListBoxHeader">
    <img src="assets/images/coin1.png" alt="">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="BTC" />
    <button class="btn-crypto btn btn-primary">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>click</button>
  </div>
  <div class="iconListBoxBody" id="iconListBoxBody">
    <ul class="iconListBoxBodyList">
      <li>
        <img src="assets/images/coin1.png" alt="">
        <span class="coinText">BTC</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="assets/images/coin2.png" alt="">
        <span class="coinText">ETH</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```